# Understanding resources of PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

If anything on page of pdf is a resource , when we call getResources method of PDPage(In API , it is written it will return a dictionary of resources),what is possible collection of things I an get ? Is it a collection of xObjects ? Which classes of the API are considered as resources ?

In PDResources defintion,it says "A set of resources available at the page/pages/stream level" .Can someone please explain what is stream level .
 Am i understanding the concept of resource wrong ?

Please help me .

Comment: resources of a PDF could be anything like image, embedded watermark, etc. Anything specific you want to ask ? COSName and PDxObject details can be had from the API docs.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Get the ExtractImages.java source code from the source code download. And use the current version (2.0.6). XObjects can be images but also forms.

Comment: Your code only looks at images which are immediate resources of a page. But they can also be indirect resources, e.g. if they are arranged on a form xobject. Or they can be inlined in the content. Have a look at the `ExtractImages` example @Tilman mentioned and use that.

Comment: sorry for confusing question earlier . I think the edited post should deliver my doubts properly . Thanks for your kind guidance .

Comment: If nobody answers, then have a look at https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf , page 83, "7.8.3
Resource Dictionaries", especially table 33 "Entries in a resource dictionary". Stream level means that resources are not just at page level, but also in forms, appearance streams and transparency groups.